# How do I submit a pull request for changes on a repo I don't own and didn't fork?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a remote repo and made changes on this clone. However, I later realized that I need to fork the repo first in order to submit a pull request. I have since forked the repo. Can I simply copy and past the contents of the non-forked repo into the forked repo or will this mess things up? Is there a better way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have created the fork, you should be able to simply change the URL of the origin for your clone to point to your fork, then push your changes to the new "origin".

```
$ git remote set-url origin http://path/to/your/fork
$ git push
```

You can also simply add a new remote in addition to the original, and push to that.

```
$ git remote add myfork http://path/to/your/fork
$ git push myfork
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any access to that repository than it's NOT possible to create a pull request. You'll need to fork it.

Comment: The OP did fork the repository. The question is how to get the changes in the local clone into the fork.